# how do i extract numbers from an image, row by row?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-tesseract, opencv

after preprocessing an image of a sudoku board (from web) with opencv, I managed to get the following picture:

[image]

looping through the contours and extracting each value using pytesseract and psm 10 (single character) resulted in junk values.

thus i  would like to slice the image to rows and try to  extract the values using the config psm 6, hoping it might work.

The approach i took is the simply numpy-slicing the row and trying to extract the values, although it doesn't work, giving me `SystemError: tile cannot extend outside image` after the first iteration although im sure the slicing occur inside the image

```
y = 1
for x in range(1, 9):
     cropped_row = mask[y*33-33:y*33-1][x*33-33:x*33-1]
     text = tess.image_to_string(np.array(cropped_row), config='--psm 6')
     y += 1
     print(text)
```

i would like some guidance to the ecorrect aproach in OCRing rows from the image

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't fare better with `psm=10`. Did you include a border and set the dpi sensibly?

Comment: if mask is numpy is should be mask[y*33-33:y*33-1, x*33-33:x*33-1], you can also loop over x and y at the same time for x,y in zip(range(1,9),range(1,9))

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this:

```py
custom_oem_psm_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6 -c tessedit_char_whitelist="0123456789"'# -c preserve_interword_spaces=0'
text= pytesseract.pytesseract.image_to_string(otsu, config=custom_oem_psm_config)
print(text)
```

Output:

```
2 91
4 67 13
2 976
4 9
9816 2754
3 1
653 7
24 85 1
46 2
```

If you want to get the exact positions of the numbers, try numpy slicing and sort them from left to right and top to bottom, then pass each number to `tesseract`.

Answer (score 0):

in the end i took a slightly different approach as explained by natancy in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59182827/how-to-get-the-cells-of-a-sudoku-grid-with-opencv) answer.

I focused on the grid lines, and removed all values so that `findcontours()` will locate all grid cells.

then, i looped through all contours and checked if they're a cell (sizewise) or some other contour.
if it is a cell, a mask made only the current cell visible (and its values when used bitwise_and(original_image, mask)
that way i could get a blank image with only a single number, and i ran that image through tesseract.
some text clearing later i got my desired output.

extraction of numbers:

```
list_of_clues = []
    for contour in contours:
        extracted_value = ''

        # create black mask
        mask = np.zeros(processed.shape, dtype=np.uint8)

        # check if contour is a cell
        area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        if 700 <= area <= 1000:  # contour is a cell
            cv2.drawContours(mask, [contour], -1, WHITE, -1)  # color everything in mask, but the contour- white
            isolated_cell = cv2.bitwise_and(processed, mask)
            isolated_cell[mask == 0] = 255  # invert isolated_cell's mask to WHITE (for tess)

            # extract text from isolated_cell
            text = tess.image_to_string(isolated_cell, config='--psm 10')

            # clean non-numbers:
            for ch in text:
                if ch.isdigit():
                    extracted_value = ch

            # calculate cell coordinates only if extracted_value exist
            if extracted_value:
            # relevant for my proj, extract grid coordinates of extracted value
                [x_pos, y_pos, wid, hei] = cv2.boundingRect(contour)    # get contour's sizes
                x_coord = int(x_pos // (grid_size_pixels / 9))          # get x row-coordinate
                y_coord = int(y_pos // (grid_size_pixels / 9))          # get y col-coordinate
                list_of_clues.append(((x_coord, y_coord), int(extracted_value)))
        else:   # contour isn't a cell
            continue
```