# Extract boxes from sudoku in opencv

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, opencv

i have converted sudoku image into sudoku grid using opencv

now i want to extract each box from image what is best way to do this?

as per my knowledge i am trying to find intersection points of lines to find corner of each box

```
class SudokuSolverPlay:
      def __init__(self, image):
         
      def __preProcess(self, img):
        """return grayscale image"""
      def __maskSudoku(self, img):
        """return masked image"""
      def __dectactEdge(self, img):
        """return sudoku grid"""
        def drawLines(src, dest, iteration=1):
            minLineLength = 100
            src = cv2.convertScaleAbs(src)
            for _ in range(iteration):
                lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image=src, rho=1, theta=np.pi / 180,
                                    threshold=100, lines=np.array([]),
                                    minLineLength=minLineLength, maxLineGap=100)
                a, b, c = lines.shape
                for i in range(a):
                    x1, y1, x2, y2 = lines[i][0][0], lines[i][0][1], lines[i][0][2], lines[i][0][3]
                    cv2.line(dest, (x1, y1), (x2, y2),255, 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
                src = cv2.convertScaleAbs(dest)

        def findVerticalLines(img):
            imgX = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 5), 0)
            kernelx = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (2, 10))
            imgY = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0)
            imgY = cv2.convertScaleAbs(imgY)
            cv2.normalize(imgY, imgY, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
            imgY = cv2.morphologyEx(imgY, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernelx, iterations=1)
            return imgY

        def findHorizontalLines(img):
            """same as above only args different"""

        img1 = np.zeros(img.shape)

        edges = cv2.Canny(img, 50, 150, apertureSize=3)
        laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(edges, cv2.CV_64F)
        drawLines(laplacian, img1, iteration=1)

        sby = findVerticalLines(img1)
        sbx = findHorizontalLines(img1)
        return img1
      def solveSudoku(self):
          gray = self.__preProcess(self.__originalImg)
          masked = self.__maskSudoku(gray)
          grid = self.__dectactGrid(masked)
                   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    colorImg = cv2.imread('sudoku1.jpg')
    solver = SudokuSolverPlay(colorImg)
    solver.solveSudoku()
```

here `findVerticalLines()` and  `findHorizontalLines()` are not able to dictect horizontal and vertical lines properly

- [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaKdC.jpg)
- [masked image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0EMf.png)
- [Canny edge dictation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1IjF.jpg)
- [hough line transform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVP2o.png)
- [horizontal lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/759Nz.png)
- [Vertical Lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzctI.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the cells of a sudoku grid with OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59182827/how-to-get-the-cells-of-a-sudoku-grid-with-opencv)

Comment: yes it has same purpose , sorry for replying "no" you can close question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve is to do a morphological operation to find vertical and horizontal lines from the canny edge image, then do a connected component analysis to find the boxes.
I have done a sample version below. You can finetune it further to make it better.
I started with the masked image as input.

```py
### reading input image
gray_scale=cv2.imread('masked_image.jpg',0)
```

#### Performing canny edge detection and adding a dilation layer

```py
img_bin = cv2.Canny(gray_scale,50,110)
dil_kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
img_bin=cv2.dilate(img_bin,dil_kernel,iterations=1)
```

Now, the dilated binary image looks like this.
[image: binary image after canny edge detection]

#### assuming minimum box size would be 20*20

```py
line_min_width = 20
```

#### finding horizontal lines

```py
kernal_h = np.ones((1,line_min_width), np.uint8)
img_bin_h = cv2.morphologyEx(img_bin, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernal_h)
```

[image: horizontal lines]

#### finding vertical lines

```py
kernal_v = np.ones((line_min_width,1), np.uint8)
img_bin_v = cv2.morphologyEx(img_bin, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernal_v)
```

[image: vertical lines]

#### merging and adding a dilation layer to close small gaps

```py
img_bin_final=img_bin_h|img_bin_v
final_kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
img_bin_final=cv2.dilate(img_bin_final,final_kernel,iterations=1)
```

[image: merged blocks]

#### applying connected component analysis

```py
ret, labels, stats,centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(~img_bin_final, connectivity=8, ltype=cv2.CV_32S)
```

#### visualising Connected component image

[image: cc image]

AS you can see, we have detected some text also as boxes, we can easily remove them with simple filter conditions, Here I'm filtering with the area should be minimum 1000 pixels condition.

#### drawing rectangles on the detected boxes.

```py
### 1 and 0 and the background and residue connected components whihc we do not require
for x,y,w,h,area in stats[2:]:
#     cv2.putText(image,'box',(x-10,y-10),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.0,(0,255,0), 2)
    if area>1000:
        cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
```

#### final output image

[image: output image]

This answer is based on my solution to find checkboxes/tables in an image using OpenCV. You can find a detailed explanation in my [blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/checkbox-table-cell-detection-using-opencv-python-332c57d25171) at Towards Data Science.
Hope this will take you closer to a solution.

#### Happy coding :)

-- edit 1

#### code to do connected component visualisation

```py
def imshow_components(labels):
    ### creating a hsv image, with a unique hue value for each label
    label_hue = np.uint8(179*labels/np.max(labels))
    ### making saturation and volume to be 255
    empty_channel = 255*np.ones_like(label_hue)
    labeled_img = cv2.merge([label_hue, empty_channel, empty_channel])
    ### converting the hsv image to BGR image
    labeled_img = cv2.cvtColor(labeled_img, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    labeled_img[label_hue==0] = 0
    ### returning the color image for visualising Connected Componenets
    return labeled_img
```

Comment: thank you for your brief answer it's working! , i want to ask you that can we make intelligent decision like when to apply erosion , dilation or different types of blur depending upon image?

Comment: how to draw image like you have drawn in `visualising Connected component image`

Comment: @JanakVaghasiya Added the code for visualizing connected components. You can start by learning all the image processing concepts. Then slowly after solving some problems using those techniques, you will be able to make those intelligent decisions yourself. It comes with practice. Keep learning. Glad to be of help. Please accept the answer too. :)