# Python3 skimage - count number of pictures

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, computer-vision, opencv3.0, scikit-image

I have an image which I'm using skimage to try and detect:

1. how many images are actually within the page - I'm expecting it to 'count' 5
2. find the corners of each image - so if it counts 5 above our maxCorners should be 5*4=20
3. draw straight lines between each corner and 'mask' each of the 5 images

right now all I got is the image being read, doing a fill holes and thats about it - guidance on the rest?

```
from scipy import ndimage as nd
import imageio
from skimage import io, filters
from scipy import ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = "C:\\Users\\Tony\\Pictures\\img807.tif"

im = io.imread(filename, as_gray=True)
val = filters.threshold_otsu(im)
drops = ndimage.binary_fill_holes(im < val)
plt.imshow(drops, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

I've tried looking at these resources:

- https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/color_exposure/plot_regional_maxima.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-color-exposure-plot-regional-maxima-py
- https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_convex_hull.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-edges-plot-convex-hull-py
- https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_corner.html

Specifically the last one corner detection...

[image]

Here's the original image:
[image]

True source link (12hrs): https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZDONYXZVkUNFT2qcEFk4nFYYnx7d8swzaD7

Comment: updated main post with image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This  [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65732398) was the key to solve this problem.

[image: Result]
[image: Result2]

Coords:

> [[(38, 11), (251, 364)], [(254, 62), (592, 266)], [(254, 312),
>
> (592, 518)], [(46, 456), (247, 797)], [(346, 557), (526, 797)]]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import itertools

#====================================================
img = cv2.imread('input.jpg', 0)
blur = cv2.blur(img,(3,3))

blur[blur>225] = 0

sobelx = cv2.Sobel(blur,cv2.CV_64F,1,0,ksize=5)
sobely = cv2.Sobel(blur,cv2.CV_64F,0,1,ksize=5)
sobel = np.sqrt( sobelx**2 + sobely**2)

sobel = (255 * sobel)/(sobel.max() - sobel.min())
sobel = sobel.astype(np.uint8)
sobel[sobel<20] = 0
sobel[sobel>20] = 255
#====================================================

_,thresh = cv2.threshold(blur,127,255,1)
thresh = thresh + sobel

median = cv2.medianBlur(thresh,3)

gray_scale = median.copy()

image = np.stack([img, img, img], axis=2)

img_bin = cv2.Canny(gray_scale,50,110)
dil_kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
img_bin=cv2.dilate(img_bin,dil_kernel,iterations=1)

line_min_width = 7

kernal_h = np.ones((2,line_min_width), np.uint8)
img_bin_h = cv2.morphologyEx(img_bin, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernal_h)

kernal_v = np.ones((line_min_width,1), np.uint8)
img_bin_v = cv2.morphologyEx(img_bin, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernal_v)

img_bin_final=img_bin_h|img_bin_v
final_kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
img_bin_final=cv2.dilate(img_bin_final,final_kernel,iterations=1)

_, _, stats, _ = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(~img_bin_final, connectivity=8, ltype=cv2.CV_32S)

coords = []
### 1 and 0 and the background and residue connected components whihc we do not require
for x,y,w,h,area in stats[2:]:
    if area>15000:
        coords.append([(x,y),(x+w,y+h)])

def bb_intersection(coords, boxA, boxB):
    # determine the (x, y)-coordinates of the intersection rectangle
    xA = max(boxA[0][0], boxB[0][0])
    yA = max(boxA[0][1], boxB[0][1])
    xB = min(boxA[1][0], boxB[1][0])
    yB = min(boxA[1][1], boxB[1][1])
    # compute the area of intersection rectangle
    interArea = max(0, xB - xA + 1) * max(0, yB - yA + 1)
    # compute the area of both rectangles
    boxAArea = (boxA[1][0] - boxA[0][0] + 1) * (boxA[1][1] - boxA[0][1] + 1)
    boxBArea = (boxB[1][0] - boxB[0][0] + 1) * (boxB[1][1] - boxB[0][1] + 1)

    if(interArea == boxAArea):
        coords.remove(boxA)
    elif(interArea == boxBArea):
        coords.remove(boxB)
#
for boxa, boxb in itertools.combinations(coords, 2):
    bb_intersection(coords, boxa, boxb)

for coord in coords:
    cv2.rectangle(image,coord[0],coord[1],(0,255,0),1)

print(coords)

plt.imshow(image)
plt.title("There are {} images".format(len(coords)))
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

### Edit:

This Answer isn't a general solution, the parameters has to be tuned accordingly, for the original image change this block, and the code will work perfectly:

```py
img = cv2.imread('input.tif', 0)

img = cv2.resize(img, (605, 830))

blur = img.copy()

blur[blur>225] = 0

sobelx = cv2.Sobel(blur,cv2.CV_64F,1,0,ksize=3)
sobely = cv2.Sobel(blur,cv2.CV_64F,0,1,ksize=3)
sobel = np.sqrt( sobelx**2 + sobely**2)

sobel = (255 * sobel)/(sobel.max() - sobel.min())
sobel = sobel.astype(np.uint8)
sobel[sobel<40] = 0
sobel[sobel>40] = 255
```

Coords:

> [[(31, 16), (240, 364)], [(253, 56), (600, 265)], [(254, 309),
>
> (605, 520)], [(40, 456), (248, 803)], [(347, 557), (534, 803)]]

Comment: strange - I only get 2 images and no bounding boxes around them... [[(2316, 494), (5579, 2500)], [(3190, 5163), (4967, 7551)]]

Comment: @Tony I used this  code with the image you provided and I have got these results, the screenshot is from the output of the `Matplotlib`, are you running the same code on this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPkTg.jpg) ?

Comment: actually no its not the true source but curious why it doesn't works on the representation of the source but not the actual thing (updated main post with link to true source)

Comment: @Tony please see the updated answer, if you want to map the coordinates to your original image, you have to multiply the coordinates with the resize ratio.

Comment: Thanks! confirmed its working now - How do you know what to tune the numbers to? ie if I switch images ?

Comment: @Tony it is empirical tuning, I don't have exact formula for doing that.

Comment: Its strange to me that it doesn't work without the resize... how do I get it working without having to resize the original?

Comment: @Tony simply you have to increase the size of the used kernels which requires much computations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227395/discussion-between-tony-and-bilal).

Comment: very interesting stuff... so if I now wanted to mask the original image based on the 5 found ? - I assume there's some math to scale up what was found to the original?

Comment: @Tony you divide the original shape by the resized shape, then you multiply this ratio for `x, y` by the `coords` and don't forget to use the `floor` function in order to make the results integers.

Comment: qq - why get the square root of the sobel? this line `sobel = np.sqrt(sobelx ** 2 + sobely ** 2)`

Comment: @Tony the magnitude of sobel filter is the sqrt of the x component squared and the y component squared.

Comment: Hi @bilal can you help with the proper settings for this image? I've been playing with all the numbers but cant seem to get it right. https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZqR0bXZ5AV0g52XgCYfMIWyAaQXAuNcmA6V ? scaled to 10% of the original in the link

Comment: @Tony This algorithm isn't general, it can't work with all images whatever they are.

Comment: @Tony this algorithm isn't general, for the new image if you want to split it, you can do that easily, just see the row of which splits the images, and split the array directly, no need to this algorithm which detects lines in the images that defines the borders mainly.

Comment: how can I visually see which row would split the images properly?

Comment: @Tony `plt.imshow(img)` >>> Zoom , `# 2747, 5630` are the rows which define the borders between your 3 images, `image1=img[:2747,:]`, `image2=img[2747:5630,:]`, and  `image3=img[5630:,:]` will split your images.