# Problem to detect custom logo or square in boxes with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

I am trying to detect how many boxes in an image with given logo 'N' for example. How can i approach this problem. My main goal is to count each different product using opencv.
So far I tried template matching with 'N' logo.
[image]

used this to count below.
[image]

From my example with haar cascade classifier training with different cascade models.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried canny and dilate and find countours?

Comment: @JosipJuros OP wants to match the logo and then count. How does contouring helps in this case ?

Comment: @balu How does it not, with the right parameters, doing len(findcountours) gives him the number of logos. since logos are boxes, and they would lit up nicely using countours.

Comment: @balu And no he isnt trying to match them, The question is how to count, he tried template matching and it didnt work. Read the question.

Comment: @JosipJuros OP says >> how many boxes in an image with given logo 'N'

Comment: @balu In both his examples all boxes have the same logo. So we dont know if ever there will be a case where they are other non N logos. We dont have that information so we cant confirm it. With the information given my comments stands valid.

Comment: @balu And for template matching or a NN classifier its much better to extract each countour (box) as its separate image wwhile creating the learning and training dataset. I know what im talking about buddy.

Comment: @JosipJuros " for template matching or a NN classifier its much better to extract each countour (box) as its separate image wwhile creating the learning and training dataset. "
Had this been your first comment, I would not have asked .

Comment: @JosipJuros N logos does not important if we can find each product box. I tried "canny and dilate and find countours" with no luck. I cannot detect all lines between products. My sample was this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65717860/extract-boxes-from-sudoku-in-opencv