# How to convert a Sudoku image with numbers to an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, image, solver, sudoku

**The sudoku**
[image: The Sudoku]

**The square from the Sudoku when `x = 1` and `y = 1`**

[image: The square of the sudoku]

I want to check the number of each square from the Sudoku and enter it to an array.
And if there is no number return 0

It's have to look like this:

```
sudoku = Image.open('sudoku.png')

for x in range(9):
    for y in range(9):
        square = sudoku.crop((112 * x, 112 * y, 112 * (x + 1), 112 * (y + 1))) #This is crop each square at x and y position
        if ('square.png') has a number:
            num = number from ('square.png')
            array[x][y] = num
        if there is no number:
            array[x][y] = 0
print(array)
        
output:
array =
    [[5, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0],
     [8, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3],
     [4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1],
     [7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6],
     [0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 5],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7, 9]]
```

I really don't know how to do that, I would greatly appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Comment: look for pytesseract package.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413216/simple-digit-recognition-ocr-in-opencv-python

Comment: If the font is always the same, you could use *"Template Matching"*... https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2021/03/22/opencv-template-matching-cv2-matchtemplate/

Answer (score 0):

Looking from other SO questions, there is significant amount of overlap. Your question, if I understand correctly, requires two parts. Taking an image of a sudoku, fitting it to a grid, then extracting the numbers, potentially solve the sudoku.

In the future, a quick google search may help you solve the question.
The pot

I have compiled some potential answers and pasted them here to keep them in one place:

**Here's a potential solution**: [From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59182827/how-to-get-the-cells-of-a-sudoku-grid-with-opencv) Credit to Nathancy

1. **Obtain binary image.** Convert image to grayscale and [adaptive threshold](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#adaptive-thresholding)
2. **Filter out all numbers and noise to isolate only boxes.** We filter using [contour area](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#contourarea) to remove the numbers since we only want each individual cell
3. **Fix grid lines.** Perform [morphological closing](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) with a [horizontal and vertical kernel](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#structuring-element) to repair grid lines.
4. **Sort each cell in top-to-bottom and left-to-right order.** We organize each cell into a sequential order using [`imutils.contours.sort_contours()`](https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils/blob/master/imutils/contours.py#L7) with the `top-to-bottom` and `left-to-right` parameter

---

Here's the initial binary image (left) and filtered out numbers + repaired grid lines + inverted image (right)

[image]
[image]

Here's a visualization of the iteration of each cell

[image]

The detected numbers in each cell

[image]

Code

```
import cv2
from imutils import contours
import numpy as np

# Load image, grayscale, and adaptive threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,57,5)

# Filter out all numbers and noise to isolate only boxes
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 1000:
        cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], -1, (0,0,0), -1)

# Fix horizontal and vertical lines
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,5))
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, vertical_kernel, iterations=9)
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,1))
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, horizontal_kernel, iterations=4)

# Sort by top to bottom and each row by left to right
invert = 255 - thresh
cnts = cv2.findContours(invert, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
(cnts, _) = contours.sort_contours(cnts, method="top-to-bottom")

sudoku_rows = []
row = []
for (i, c) in enumerate(cnts, 1):
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 50000:
        row.append(c)
        if i % 9 == 0:  
            (cnts, _) = contours.sort_contours(row, method="left-to-right")
            sudoku_rows.append(cnts)
            row = []

# Iterate through each box
for row in sudoku_rows:
    for c in row:
        mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1)
        result = cv2.bitwise_and(image, mask)
        result[mask==0] = 255
        cv2.imshow('result', result)
        cv2.waitKey(175)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('invert', invert)
cv2.waitKey()
```

**Here is another Solution** [From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59182827/how-to-get-the-cells-of-a-sudoku-grid-with-opencv) Credit to Pygirl
**Steps:**

1. Image PreProcessing ( closing operation )
2. Finding Sudoku Square and Creating Mask Image
3. Finding Vertical lines
4. Finding Horizontal Lines
5. Finding Grid Points
6. Correcting the defects
7. Extracting the digits from each cell

#### Code:

```
# ==========import the necessary packages============
import imutils
import numpy as np
import cv2
from transform import four_point_transform
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import math
from skimage.filters import threshold_local

# =============== For Transformation ==============
def order_points(pts):
    """initialzie a list of coordinates that will be ordered
    such that the first entry in the list is the top-left,
    the second entry is the top-right, the third is the
    bottom-right, and the fourth is the bottom-left"""

    rect = np.zeros((4, 2), dtype = "float32")
 
    # the top-left point will have the smallest sum, whereas
    # the bottom-right point will have the largest sum
    s = pts.sum(axis = 1)
    rect[0] = pts[np.argmin(s)]
    rect[2] = pts[np.argmax(s)]
 
    # now, compute the difference between the points, the
    # top-right point will have the smallest difference,
    # whereas the bottom-left will have the largest difference
    diff = np.diff(pts, axis = 1)
    rect[1] = pts[np.argmin(diff)]
    rect[3] = pts[np.argmax(diff)]
 
    # return the ordered coordinates
    return rect


def four_point_transform(image, pts):
    # obtain a consistent order of the points and unpack them
    # individually
    rect = order_points(pts)
    (tl, tr, br, bl) = rect
 
    # compute the width of the new image, which will be the
    # maximum distance between bottom-right and bottom-left
    # x-coordiates or the top-right and top-left x-coordinates
    widthA = np.sqrt(((br[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((br[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
    widthB = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - tl[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - tl[1]) ** 2))
    maxWidth = max(int(widthA), int(widthB))
 
    # compute the height of the new image, which will be the
    # maximum distance between the top-right and bottom-right
    # y-coordinates or the top-left and bottom-left y-coordinates
    heightA = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - br[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - br[1]) ** 2))
    heightB = np.sqrt(((tl[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((tl[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
    maxHeight = max(int(heightA), int(heightB))
 
    # now that we have the dimensions of the new image, construct
    # the set of destination points to obtain a "birds eye view",
    # (i.e. top-down view) of the image, again specifying points
    # in the top-left, top-right, bottom-right, and bottom-left
    # order
    dst = np.array([
        [0, 0],
        [maxWidth - 1, 0],
        [maxWidth - 1, maxHeight - 1],
        [0, maxHeight - 1]], dtype = "float32")
 
    # compute the perspective transform matrix and then apply it
    M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(rect, dst)
    warped = cv2.warpPerspective(image, M, (maxWidth, maxHeight))
 
    # return the warped image
    return warped

############## To show image ##############
def show_image(img,title):
    cv2.imshow(title, img) 
    cv2.waitKey(0) 
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()  


def find_largest_feature(inp_img, scan_tl=None, scan_br=None):
    """
    Uses the fact the `floodFill` function returns a bounding box of the area it filled to find the biggest
    connected pixel structure in the image. Fills this structure in white, reducing the rest to black.
    """
    img = inp_img.copy()  # Copy the image, leaving the original untouched
    height, width = img.shape[:2]

    max_area = 0
    seed_point = (None, None)

    if scan_tl is None:
        scan_tl = [0, 0]

    if scan_br is None:
        scan_br = [width, height]

    # Loop through the image
    for x in range(scan_tl[0], scan_br[0]):
        for y in range(scan_tl[1], scan_br[1]):
            # Only operate on light or white squares
            if img.item(y, x) == 255 and x < width and y < height:  # Note that .item() appears to take input as y, x
                area = cv2.floodFill(img, None, (x, y), 64)
                if area[0] > max_area:  # Gets the maximum bound area which should be the grid
                    max_area = area[0]
                    seed_point = (x, y)

    # Colour everything grey (compensates for features outside of our middle scanning range
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            if img.item(y, x) == 255 and x < width and y < height:
                cv2.floodFill(img, None, (x, y), 64)

    mask = np.zeros((height + 2, width + 2), np.uint8)  # Mask that is 2 pixels bigger than the image

    # Highlight the main feature
    if all([p is not None for p in seed_point]):
        cv2.floodFill(img, mask, seed_point, 255)

    

    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            if img.item(y, x) == 64:  # Hide anything that isn't the main feature
                cv2.floodFill(img, mask, (x, y), 0)
    
    return img


################# Preprocessing of sudoku image ###############
def preprocess(image,case):
    ratio = image.shape[0] / 500.0
    orig = image.copy()
    image = imutils.resize(image, height = 500)

    if case == True:
    
        gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(image,(5,5),0)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(gray,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        mask = np.zeros((gray.shape),np.uint8)
        kernel1 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(11,11))

        close = cv2.morphologyEx(gray,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel1)
        div = np.float32(gray)/(close)
        res = np.uint8(cv2.normalize(div,div,0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX))
        res2 = cv2.cvtColor(res,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        edged = cv2.Canny(res, 75, 200)
    
        cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]
        cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:5]
 
        # loop over the contours
        for c in cnts:
            # approximate the contour
            rect = cv2.boundingRect(c)
            area = cv2.contourArea(c)

            cv2.rectangle(edged.copy(), (rect[0],rect[1]), (rect[2]+rect[0],rect[3]+rect[1]), (0,0,0), 2)
            peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
            approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)
 
            # if our approximated contour has four points, then we
            # can assume that we have found our screen
            if len(approx) == 4:
                screenCnt = approx
                #print(screenCnt)
                break
         
        # show the contour (outline) of the piece of paper
        #print(screenCnt)
        cv2.drawContours(image, [screenCnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    
        # apply the four point transform to obtain a top-down
        # view of the original image    
        warped = four_point_transform(orig, screenCnt.reshape(4, 2) * ratio)
        warped1 = cv2.resize(warped,(610,610))
        warp = cv2.cvtColor(warped, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
        T = threshold_local(warp, 11, offset = 10, method = "gaussian")
        warp = (warp > T).astype("uint8") * 255
        th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(warp,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,2) 
        kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
        dilation =cv2.GaussianBlur(th3,(5,5),0)

    else :
        
        warped = image
        warped1 = cv2.resize(warped,(610,610))
        warp = cv2.cvtColor(warped, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
        T = threshold_local(warp, 11, offset = 10, method = "gaussian")
        warp = (warp > T).astype("uint8") * 255
        th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(warp,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,2)

    #show_image(warped1,"preprocessed")

    return th3,warped1,warped

def grids(img,warped2):
    #print("im:",img.shape)
    img2 = img.copy()
    img = np.zeros((500,500,3), np.uint8)

    ratio2 = 3
    kernel_size = 3
    lowThreshold = 30

    frame = img

    img = cv2.resize(frame,(610,610))

    for i in range(10):
        cv2.line(img, (0,(img.shape[0]//9)*i),(img.shape[1],(img.shape[0]//9)*i), (255, 255, 255), 3, 1)
        cv2.line(warped2, (0,(img.shape[0]//9)*i),(img.shape[1],(img.shape[0]//9)*i), (125, 0, 55), 3, 1)
    
    for j in range(10):
        cv2.line(img, ((img.shape[1]//9)*j, 0), ((img.shape[1]//9)*j, img.shape[0]), (255, 255, 255), 3, 1)
        cv2.line(warped2, ((img.shape[1]//9)*j, 0), ((img.shape[1]//9)*j, img.shape[0]), (125, 0, 55), 3, 1)
  
    #show_image(warped2,"grids")
    return img

############### Finding out the intersection pts to get the grids #########
def grid_points(img,warped2):
    img1 = img.copy()
    kernelx = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(2,10))

    dx = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_16S,1,0)
    dx = cv2.convertScaleAbs(dx)
    c=cv2.normalize(dx,dx,0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
    c = cv2.morphologyEx(c,cv2.MORPH_DILATE,kernelx,iterations = 1)
    cy = cv2.cvtColor(c,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    closex = cv2.morphologyEx(cy,cv2.MORPH_DILATE,kernelx,iterations = 1)

    kernely = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(10,2))
    dy = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_16S,0,2)
    dy = cv2.convertScaleAbs(dy)
    c = cv2.normalize(dy,dy,0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
    c = cv2.morphologyEx(c,cv2.MORPH_DILATE,kernely,iterations = 1)
    cy = cv2.cvtColor(c,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    closey = cv2.morphologyEx(cy,cv2.MORPH_DILATE,kernelx,iterations = 1)

    res = cv2.bitwise_and(closex,closey)
    #gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(res,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    kernel = np.ones((6,6),np.uint8)


    # Perform morphology
    se = np.ones((8,8), dtype='uint8')
    image_close = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, se)
    image_close = cv2.morphologyEx(image_close, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

    contour, hier = cv2.findContours        (image_close,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = sorted(contour, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[:100]
    centroids = []
    for cnt in cnts:
    
        mom = cv2.moments(cnt)
        (x,y) = int(mom['m10']/mom['m00']), int(mom['m01']/mom['m00'])
        cv2.circle(img1,(x,y),4,(0,255,0),-1)
        cv2.circle(warped2,(x,y),4,(0,255,0),-1)
        centroids.append((x,y))

    #show_image(warped2,"grid_points")


    Points = np.array(centroids,dtype = np.float32)
    c = Points.reshape((100,2))
    c2 = c[np.argsort(c[:,1])]

    b = np.vstack([c2[i*10:(i+1)*10][np.argsort(c2[i*10:(i+1)*10,0])] for i in range(10)])
    bm = b.reshape((10,10,2))

    return c2,bm,cnts

############ Recognize digit images to number #############
def image_to_num(c2):     
    img = 255-c2
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang="eng",config='--psm 6 --oem 3') #builder=builder)
    return list(text)[0]

###### To get the digit at the particular cell #############
def get_digit(c2,bm,warped1,cnts):
    num = []
    centroidx = np.empty((9, 9))
    centroidy = np.empty((9, 9))
    global list_images
    list_images = []
    for i in range(0,9):
        for j in range(0,9):

            x1,y1 = bm[i][j] # bm[0] row1 
            x2,y2 = bm[i+1][j+1]
            
            coordx = ((x1+x2)//2)
            coordy = ((y1+y2)//2)
            centroidx[i][j] = coordx
            centroidy[i][j] = coordy
            crop = warped1[int(x1):int(x2),int(y1):int(y2)]
            crop = imutils.resize(crop, height=69,width=67)
            c2 = cv2.cvtColor(crop, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            c2 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(c2,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
                cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,2)
            kernel = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8)
            #c2 = cv2.morphologyEx(c2, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
            c2= cv2.copyMakeBorder(c2,5,5,5,5,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=(0,0,0))
            no = 0
            shape=c2.shape
            w=shape[1]
            h=shape[0]
            mom = cv2.moments(c2)
            (x,y) = int(mom['m10']/mom['m00']), int(mom['m01']/mom['m00']) 
            c2 = c2[14:70,15:62]
            contour, hier = cv2.findContours (c2,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
            if cnts is not None:
                cnts = sorted(contour, key=cv2.contourArea,reverse=True)[:1]

            for cnt in cnts:
                x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
                aspect_ratio = w/h
#               print(aspect_ratio)
                area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
                #print(area)
                if area>120 and cnt.shape[0]>15 and aspect_ratio>0.2 and aspect_ratio<=0.9 : 
                    #print("area:",area)
                    c2 = find_largest_feature(c2)
                    #show_image(c2,"box2")
                    contour, hier = cv2.findContours (c2,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
                    cnts = sorted(contour, key=cv2.contourArea,reverse=True)[:1]
                    for cnt in cnts:
                        rect = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
                        #cv2.rectangle(c2, (rect[0],rect[1]), (rect[2]+rect[0],rect[3]+rect[1]), (255,255,255), 2)
                        c2 = c2[rect[1]:rect[3]+rect[1],rect[0]:rect[2]+rect[0]]
                        c2= cv2.copyMakeBorder(c2,5,5,5,5,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=(0,0,0))
                        list_images.append(c2)
                    #show_image(c2,"box")
                    no = image_to_num(c2)
            num.append(no)
    centroidx = np.transpose(centroidx)
    centroidy = np.transpose(centroidy)
    return c2, num, centroidx, centroidy

######## creating matrix and filling numbers exist in the orig image #######
def sudoku_matrix(num):
    c = 0
    grid = np.empty((9, 9))
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            grid[i][j] = int(num[c])
            
            c += 1
    grid = np.transpose(grid)
    return grid

######## Creating board to show the puzzle result in terminal##############
def board(arr):
    for i in range(9):
    
        if i%3==0 :
                print("+",end="")
                print("-------+"*3)
                
        for j in range(9):
            if j%3 ==0 :
                print("",end="| ")
            print(int(arr[i][j]),end=" ")
      
        print("",end="|")       
        print()
      
    print("+",end="")
    print("-------+"*3)
    return arr      
   
def check_col(arr,num,col):
    if  all([num != arr[i][col] for i in range(9)]):
        return True
    return False
    

def check_row(arr,num,row):
    if  all([num != arr[row][i] for i in range(9)]):
        return True
    return False


def check_cell(arr,num,row,col):
    sectopx = 3 * (row//3)
    sectopy = 3 * (col//3)
          
    for i in range(sectopx, sectopx+3):
        for j in range(sectopy, sectopy+3):
            if arr[i][j] == num:
                return True
    return False


def empty_loc(arr,l):
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            if arr[i][j] == 0:
                l[0]=i
                l[1]=j
                return True              
    return False

#### Solving sudoku by back tracking############
def sudoku(arr):
    l=[0,0]

    if not empty_loc(arr,l):
        return True
    
    row = l[0]
    col = l[1]
                
    for num in range(1,10):
        if check_row(arr,num,row) and check_col(arr,num,col) and not check_cell(arr,num,row,col):
            arr[row][col] = int(num) 
            
            if(sudoku(arr)):
                return True
 
            # failure, unmake & try again
            arr[row][col] = 0
                    
    return False

def overlay(arr,num,img,cx,cy):
    no = -1
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            no += 1 
            #cv2.putText(img,str(no), (int(cx[i][j]),int(cy[i][j])),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 2)
            if num[no] == 0:
                
                cv2.putText(img,str(int(arr[j][i])), (int(cx[i][j]-4),int(cy[i][j])+8),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 4)
                
    cv2.imshow("Sudoku",img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

---

```
case = "False" # If transformation is required set True 
image = cv2.imread("QupKb.png")

th3,warped1,warped = preprocess(image,case)
warped2 = warped1.copy()
img = grids(warped,warped2)
c2,bm,cnts = grid_points(img,warped2)
c2,num,cx,cy = get_digit(c2,bm,warped1,cnts)
grid = sudoku_matrix(num)
if(sudoku(grid)):
    arr = board(grid)
    overlay(arr,num,warped1,cx,cy)

else:
    print("There is no solution")
```

---

**warped:**

[image: warped]

**th3:**

[image: th3]

**warped2:**

[image: warped2]

**sudoku result:**
[image]

---

**All the extracted digits:**

```
########## To view all the extracted digits ###############
_, axs = plt.subplots(1, len(list_images), figsize=(24, 24))
axs = axs.flatten()
for img, ax in zip(list_images, axs):
    ax.imshow(cv2.resize(img,(64,64)))
plt.show()
```

[image: digits]

**References:**

- [grid
  points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196198/how-to-remove-convexity-defects-in-a-sudoku-square)
- [get features (of
  digits)](https://medium.com/@neshpatel/solving-sudoku-part-ii-9a7019d196a2)
- [Images
  samples](https://github.com/eatonk/sudoku-image-solver/tree/master/sudoku_images)

**Note:** The sorting idea was adapted from an old previous answer in [Rubrik cube solver color extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916870/python-opencv-rubiks-cube-solver-color-extraction).
Here are some sources that I used to help compile this answer, the code of which can be accredited to these source:

[Contour Area](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#contourarea)

[Morphological Closing](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html)

[Another SO question or answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59182827/how-to-get-the-cells-of-a-sudoku-grid-with-opencv)

[Rubiks cube approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916870/python-opencv-rubiks-cube-solver-color-extraction)